# Swagger configuration in spring boot project, for same request model, need to display different responses, example in request model

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest, swagger

Below is the definition of my 2 APIs:

```
    @PutMapping("/valA")
    public ResponseEntity<DummyResponse> getValA(@RequestBody DummyModel model) {
        DummyResponse dummyResponse = new DummyResponse();
        dummyResponse.setResA(model.getValA());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dummyResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

```
    @PutMapping("/valB")
    public ResponseEntity<DummyResponse> getValB(@RequestBody DummyModel model) {
        DummyResponse dummyResponse = new DummyResponse();
        dummyResponse.setResB(model.getValB());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dummyResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

DummyModel.java

```
package com.dummy.mo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class DummyModel implements Serializable {
    private String valA;
    private String valB;
}
```

Now in swagger, For both the apis, example shows like below:

[image]

But, my reuirement is to show only valA in first api and valB in second api in swagger example. I mean, I only want to show the params which are required to the corresponding APIs.

Is there any annotation or configuration out there to define required request parameters at API/Controller level.
Note that: I cannot change the API structure or model class.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you split the DummyModel class.

What if we, create 2 interfaces like below :

```
public interface One {
        
   String valB = null;
    
   public default String getBalB(){
       return valB;
    }
}

public interface Two {
    String valA = null;

    public default String getBalA(){
        return valA;
    }
}
```

Dummy Model class

```
@Data
public class DummyModel implements One, Two{

    private String valB = null;
    private String valA = null;

    public DummyModel(String valA,String valB) {
        this.valB = valB;
        this.valA = valA;
    }
}
```

Update your apis :

```
@RestController
public class TestClass {

    @PutMapping("/valA")
    public ResponseEntity<One> getValA(@RequestBody One model) {
        DummyModel dummyResponse = new DummyModel(null,model.getBalB());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dummyResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping("/valB")
    public ResponseEntity<Two> getValB(@RequestBody Two model) {
        DummyModel dummyResponse = new DummyModel(model.getBalA(),null);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(dummyResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: I mentioned that we can not change the api structure. I need to achieve this via swagger configuration.